# How to use a variable in an exec shell with PHP?

Tags: php, shell

Would you help me to use an `exec` shell in my PHP code? My problem was in using the command `grep`. I had used this code: `grep $_POST['key']`, so is it right or not?

```
<form id="invite2" action="accesss.php" method="POST" >
key word used to filter in access.log: <br><br>
<input type="text" name="key"  />
<input type="submit" value="recherche" name="submit1"/><br>
</form>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit1']))
  {
$results = shell_exec("cat /var/log/syslog | grep $_POST['key'] | sed s/'^.*apache2'/''/g | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr | cat ");
echo "<pre>".$results . "</pre>";

}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit1']))
  {
$results = shell_exec("cat /var/log/syslog | grep" . $_POST['key'] . "| sed s/'^.*apache2'/''/g | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr | cat ");
echo "<pre>".$results . "</pre>";

}
?>
```

**Don't use this though** - it's unsecure as hell.

Comment: i had used this block of code wich connect with the base is it right and can u help me about it please : else if(isset($_POST['submit5']))
{
mysql_connect('127.0.0.1',"root"," ") or die("erreur de connexion au serveur");
 mysql_select_db("lastnline");
     $sql='Select * from motclef';  
 $res=mysql_query($sql);
           while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res))
     
 {
$results = shell_exec("cat /var/log/apache2/access.log | grep" . $row['nom'] . "| sed s/'^.*apache2'/''/g | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr | cat ");
echo $results ;

 }  
}

Comment: Please make a new question or edit your question above.